# How to convert VSOP's xyz coordinates to heliocentric spherical lbr coordinates?

Tags: the-sun, algorithm

I ran [VSOP2013](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/abs/2013/09/aa21843-13/aa21843-13.html) in Fortran, and I now have the following position $x, y, z$ as well as velocity $v_x, v_y, v_z$ data.

How do I convert the position to [heliocentric ecliptic spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system#Spherical_coordinates) $l, b, r$?

```
PLANETARY EPHEMERIS VSOP2013  EMB     
Ecliptic   Heliocentric Coordinates:  X,Y,Z (au)  X',Y',Z' (au/d)  - Dynamical Frame J2000

Julian Day 2415021.0   
-0.2054467990    0.9615310525    0.0002141233   -0.0171063024   -0.0036576954   -0.0000011815
```

Comment: You're asking how to convert rectangular coordinates to spherical?

Comment: whats L, B, R?  I have never heard of those coordinates. At least none by that name or TLA.

Comment: l, b,r are heliocentric solar coordinates. l is longitude (measured from vernal equinox) b is ecliptic latiude (north positive) r is heliocentric distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system

Comment: thanks, that sure sounds like spherical coordinates to me. lol

Comment: x,y,z - do you know if they are earth rotating coordinates or just earth centered non-rotating?

Comment: @barrycarter correct!

Comment: @MuhamadNW That's fairly basic math, no offense. Try googling. Formulas abound.

Comment: thank you @barrycarter i thought it was different from the basic math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the numbers and comparing to [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), the best match is to the position of the Earth-Moon Barycenter in heliocentric coordinates. That's of course consistent with the data being labeled as:  `EMB, Ecliptic Heliocentric Coordinates`.

If you can live with some small uncertainties due to the details of how coordinate transforms may evolve over time, *I believe* you can just apply some simple trigonometry. You can confirm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system#Rectangular_coordinates).

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$

$$l = tan^{-1}(y/x)$$

$$b = sin^{-1}(z/r)$$

---

[image]

```
Data in Question: for JD 2415021.0
position (AU):     [-0.2054467990,  0.9615310525,  0.0002141233]
velocity (AU/day): [-0.0171063024, -0.0036576954, -0.0000011815]

JPL Horizions Earth-Moon barycenter J2000 Heliocentric for JD 2415021.0
position (AU):     [-0.2054465857,  0.9615310983,  0.00021393097] 
velocity (AU/day): [-0.0171063032, -0.0036576916, -0.00000118253]

JPL Horizions Earth J2000 Heliocentric for JD 2415021.0
position (AU):     [-0.2054522688,  0.9615603123,  0.00021303115] 
velocity (AU/day): [-0.0171136285, -0.0036594066, -0.00000182603]

JPL Horizions Earth J2000 Solar System barycenter for JD 2415021.0
position (AU):     [-0.2022720210,  0.9679285296,  0.00010939456]
velocity (AU/day): [-0.0171209826, -0.0036556277, -0.00000165111]
```

Comment: I see you've been asking python questions about VSOP2013 in SO. You might want to look at the two Python packages [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) based on VSOP87 according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487339/3904031) and also definitely check out [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/). Skyfield uses the same [Development Ephemerides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris) as [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) but is very new, modern, and easy to use.